# PowerShell throws "access is denied" exception when using Azure Active Directory authentication to Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10, azure-active-directory

I have several Windows 10 systems joined to my Azure Active Directory (AzureAD) tenant. I am trying to use the PowerShell `Get-WmiObject` command to remotely query some data from them. When I try to authenticate to the remote systems, I simply get an "Access is Denied" message, even though I'm using the appropriate credentials.

```bsh
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName remotepc -Credential azuread\adminuser -Class Win32_BIOS
```

**Question**: How can I properly authenticate to the remote systems, using my Azure Active Directory user account from PowerShell?

Comment: I'm not familiar with azure but is there an `az login` command?

Comment: what is "appropriate credentials?" is that the same user you used to join the machine to azure ad?

Comment: @alphaz18 Yes, same user that I used to join the system, and same user that I use to login to the system locally.

Answer (score 0):

Is the remote system already prepared for PS remoting?

Try this on the remote machine to ensure that WinRM is set up correctly:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

**About Remote Troubleshooting:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7

**About Remote Requirements:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-7

Comment: I'm not using WS-Man remoting. The Get-WmiObject command uses DCOM/RPC remoting, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: pwhdsh, fyi.. [Trevor Sullivan has been an MS PowerShell MVP for many years and has many articles and [videos on PowerShell/VScode, etc.](https://www.youtube.com/user/pcgeek86), as well, as on the PSRemoting topic. I would say he is up to date on all the PSRemoting. [You don't need WSMan for remoting, for several PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq?view=powershell-7) and  [as documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-on-a-remote-computer-by-using-powershell)

Comment: Trevor, we know DCOM is often blocked at firewalls, but I am fairly certain you would have looked at that already, but just asking to be sure, meaning, if that has been opened or not. Yet, since you say your AAD tenant instance, I would assume that it is.

Comment: A couple of other things here.  If you do Get-MsoUser what userType comes back for the account you are using? Did you try using your FQDN names instead? Meaning,  TSulliva@TSullivan.com instead of the NetBIOS way you are showing?